# Is there a proposal for ? operator / null-conditional operator for C++?

Tags: c++, c++20

Rust has a `?` operator for error propagation without exceptions. When a function returns a `Result` or `Option` type, one can write:

```
let a = get_a()?;
```

Which effectively means:

```
let _a = get_a();
let mut a = match _a {
    Ok(value) => value,
    Err(e) => return Err(e),
}
```

Or, in other words, if the returned value contains an error, the function will return and propagate the error. All of this happens in just one char, so the code is compact without too many `if (err) return err` branches.

Same concept exists in C#: [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

In C++, the closest thing I was able to find is [tl::expected](https://github.com/TartanLlama/expected) and Boost.outcome. But those two require use of e. g. lambdas to achieve same thing and it's not as concise. From what I understand, affecting control flow like that would require some kind of language feature or extension.

I tried to find a proposal that would implement it or be related at least and couldn't. Is there a C++ proposal for implementing it?

Comment: C++ has proposal that speeds up exceptions so they'll be a usable tool for flow control without any significant loss of performance unlike current exception mechanisms.

Comment: There are no current standard types to apply your `?`. and `?` might be problematic with ternary operator...

Comment: @Jarod42 it ain't mine, as in, it's not a new concept. And also that's the reason I'm asking :)

Comment: I meant, I think we should first have some proposal for `expected` or similar before having a new "macro operator" (allow to conditionally exit current function). exceptions seems currently the thing which look like the more as final syntax...

Comment: Boost.Leaf is also an effort towards this direction

Comment: "*But those two require use of e. g. lambdas to achieve same thing*" You could also just do a conditional check. No need for lambdas.

Comment: @NicolBolas correct, I mostly see using lambdas as a way to keep code more readable. If you extract code into functions you don't need lambdas for e. g. and_then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such proposal. Nor is there likely to be one in the immediate future. The C++ standard library does not even have value-or-error types at the moment, so having an operator whose sole purpose is to automatically unpack such types seems very cart-before-the-horse.

At present, the C++ committee seems [more interested in finding a way to make exception throwing cheaper](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p0709r4.pdf), and thus moving towards a Python-like environment where you just *use exceptions* for this sort of thing.

For the sake of completeness (and for no other reason), I will mention that `co_await` exists. I bring this up because you can (ab)use `co_await` to do something behaviorally equivalent to what you want.

When you `co_await` on an object, the coroutine machinery transforms the given expression into its final form. And the coroutine machinery can suspend execution of the function, returning control to the caller. And this mechanism has the power to affect the return value of the function. Which looks kind of like a normal function *return*, if you squint hard enough.

With all this in mind, you can therefore (ab)use coroutine machinery for functions that return value-or-error types like `expected`. You can `co_await` on some value-or-error type. If the expression is a value, then the `co_await` will not suspend the function, and it will unpack the value from the expression. If the expression is an error, then `co_await` will "suspend" the function and propagate the error value into the return value for that function. But in "suspending" it, the coroutine machinery will never actually schedule execution of the coroutine to resume, so once control is given back to the caller, the coroutine is terminated.

That having been said, you should **never do this**. A non-comprehensive list of reasons why being:

1. It doesn't make sense, based on what `co_await` is *intended* to do. A coroutine is supposed to be a function that suspends execution in order to resume it when some asynchronous process is complete. That is, the function "await"s on something. But you're not waiting on anything; you're (ab)using `co_await` to create the effect of a transform-or-return. As such, a person reading the code won't necessarily know what's going on, since nothing is actually being "awaited" on.
2. Your function becomes a coroutine, and being a coroutine creates issues. That is, because coroutines are *expected* to be resumed, they have a certain amount of baggage. For example, `co_return` does *not* allow for guaranteed elision (and probably cannot be changed to permit it in the future). Every coroutine has a promise object that acts as an intermediary between the internal function and its return value. Coroutines are dynamically allocated, and not dynamically allocating them is considered an *optimization*. So compilers may not optimize this case out. And so on.
3. You can't have a "normal" coroutine that *also* propagates errors in this way. A function either uses `co_await` for errors or it uses `co_await` for actual awaiting; it can't do both. So if you want a coroutine that can fail, you have to do things manually.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same effect by combining the [pattern matching proposal](https://wg21.link/p1371), the proposal for [`std::expected`](https://wg21.link/p0323), and writing a macro:

```cpp
#define TRY(e) inspect (e) {                                                   \
        <typename remove_cvref_t<decltype(e)>::error_type> err => return err; \
        <auto> val => val;                                                    \
    }
```

The difficulty here is that while in Rust, every `Result` instantiation still has `Ok` and `Err` types, we don't have as convenient a mechanism to pull out what the error type would be from `std::expected`.

And the real implementation of this would probably want to generalize a bit to handle other `Result`-like error handling types that might expose the error variant slightly differently.

Comment: The macro is exactly the issue though. Macro is already possible now and I think Boost uses it.